# Get uri of picture taken by camera

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

When the user takes a picture with the camera, I want the image displayed in an ImageView and I want to save the Uri to an online database. I heard saving the Uri of a picture is better than saving the path.

So this is how I start the camera:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getFile(getActivity()))); 
String a = String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(getFile(getActivity())));
intent.putExtra("photo_uri", a);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

where

```
private File getFile(Context context){
  File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Myapp");
  if (!directory.exists()) {
       directory.mkdirs();
  }
  String filename = "bl" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
  File newFile = new File(directory, filename);

  return newFile;
}
```

In onActivityResult:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
String photo_uri = extras.getString("photo_uri"); //null
```

This is always null. Btw before sending the intent the Uri looks like file://... instead of content:// which is the uri when I open an image from the gallery. I don't know if that's a problem.

Also, should I save the path instead of the Uri to the database? I read that the Uri can be complicated in certain phones or Android versions. When I let the user select an image from the gallery, I save the Uri to the database, so I think the best way is saving the Uri in this case as well.

I tried out many variations, but I get null every time I try to pass a variable with the intent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After starting the intent:

```
Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(intentPicture,PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

In `onActivityResult`:

```
case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:

   Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
   InputStream imageStream = null;
   try {
       imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);   
break;
```

That's all.