# How to get last picture taken by user/camera

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I get last picture from gallery (camera roll) using flutter?

I would like to display this photo as a thumbnail like this:

[image]

I know that it's possible in android [Get uri of picture taken by camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955281/get-uri-of-picture-taken-by-camera) and in IOS [Swift - how to get last taken 3 photos from photo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259961/swift-how-to-get-last-taken-3-photos-from-photo-library/31167502)

Is there a tool, lib, media API that could help me with that?

Answer (score 6):

You can try using this library. [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager)

```
  List<AssetEntity> assets = [];
  _fetchAssets() async {
    final albums = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(type: RequestType.all);
    final recentAlbum = albums.first;
    final recentAssets = await recentAlbum.getAssetListRange(
      start: 0, // start at index 0
      end: 1, // end at a very big index (to get all the assets)
    );
    print(recentAssets);

    setState(() => assets = recentAssets);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use platform channels ,, as you know it's native solution

https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-platform-channels-ce7f540a104e

https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: I don't want to write custom code for android and ios :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do this through a dialog, you can use the [image picker plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) which allows you to go through the camera's image gallery and the user can select the image (including the last image).

If you want this done completely programmatically, someone implemented a pull request for this very feature here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/676, but it hasn't been accepted because it needs some tests. You could copy the code from that PR, or add some tests, and then get it accepted into the repo!